ERROR in ./node_modules/@highcharts/dashboards/modules/layout.js
I am creating a dashboard in react app using highcharts library but an error occurred while creating it.

ERROR in ./node_modules/@highcharts/dashboards/modules/layout.js

My script in js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import Dashboards from '@highcharts/dashboards';

import axios from 'axios';
import DataGrid from '@highcharts/dashboards/datagrid';
import LayoutModule from '@highcharts/dashboards/modules/layout';

LayoutModule(Dashboards);

Dashboards.HighchartsPlugin.custom.connectHighcharts(Highcharts);
Dashboards.DataGridPlugin.custom.connectDataGrid(DataGrid);

Dashboards.PluginHandler.addPlugin(Dashboards.HighchartsPlugin);
Dashboards.PluginHandler.addPlugin(Dashboards.DataGridPlugin);

const Dashboard = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('https://stage-backend-2024.epravaha.com/api/farmer/count/statewise');
      setData(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
  };

  // Calculate total number of farmer registrations
  const totalRegistrations = data.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.count, 0);

  // Calculate number of states
  const totalStates = data.length;

  // Data for bar chart
  const barChartData = data.map(item => ({ name: item.statename, y: item.count }));

  // Data for pie chart
  const pieChartData = data.map(item => ({ name: item.statename, y: item.count }));

  // Data for donut chart
  const donutChartData = data.map(item => ({ name: item.statename, y: item.count }));

  // Data for column chart
  const columnChartData = data.map(item => ({ name: item.statename, y: item.count }));

  useEffect(() => {
    Dashboards.board('container', {
      editMode: {
        enabled: true,
        contextMenu: {
          enabled: true,
          items: ['editMode'],
        },
      },
      gui: {
        layouts: [{
          id: 'layout-1',
          rows: [{
            cells: [{
              id: 'row-1',
              layout: {
                cells: [{
                  id: 'kpi-chart1',
                  componentType: 'KPI',
                  data: {
                    value: totalRegistrations,
                    label: 'Total Farmer Registrations'
                  }
                }, {
                  id: 'kpi-chart2',
                  componentType: 'KPI',
                  data: {
                    value: totalStates,
                    label: 'Total States'
                  }
                }]
              }
            }]
          }, {
            cells: [{
              id: 'row-2',
              layout: {
                cells: [{
                  id: 'bar-chart',
                  componentType: 'Highcharts',
                  chartType: 'bar',
                  data: barChartData,
                  options: {
                    chart: {
                      type: 'bar'
                    },
                    title: {
                      text: 'Bar Chart'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                      categories: barChartData.map(item => item.name)
                    },
                    series: [{
                      name: 'Number of Farmer Registrations',
                      data: barChartData.map(item => item.y)
                    }]
                  }
                }, {
                  id: 'pie-chart',
                  componentType: 'Highcharts',
                  chartType: 'pie',
                  data: pieChartData,
                  options: {
                    chart: {
                      type: 'pie'
                    },
                    title: {
                      text: 'Pie Chart'
                    },
                    series: [{
                      name: 'Number of Farmer Registrations',
                      data: pieChartData
                    }]
                  }
                }]
              }
            }]
          }, {
            cells: [{
              id: 'row-3',
              layout: {
                cells: [{
                  id: 'donut-chart',
                  componentType: 'Highcharts',
                  chartType: 'pie',
                  data: donutChartData,
                  options: {
                    chart: {
                      type: 'pie'
                    },
                    title: {
                      text: 'Donut Chart'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                      pie: {
                        innerSize: '50%',
                        depth: 45
                      }
                    },
                    series: [{
                      name: 'Number of Farmer Registrations',
                      data: donutChartData
                    }]
                  }
                }, {
                  id: 'column-chart',
                  componentType: 'Highcharts',
                  chartType: 'column',
                  data: columnChartData,
                  options: {
                    chart: {
                      type: 'column'
                    },
                    title: {
                      text: 'Column Chart'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                      categories: columnChartData.map(item => item.name)
                    },
                    series: [{
                      name: 'Number of Farmer Registrations',
                      data: columnChartData.map(item => item.y)
                    }]
                  }
                }]
              }
            }]
          }]
        }]
      }
    });
  }, [totalRegistrations, totalStates, barChartData, pieChartData, donutChartData, columnChartData]);

  return (
    <div id="container"></div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;


In my code i want to make a dashboard in my react app.here i'm providing my dashboard.js file.
I want a dashboard that comes up in my react app.

Hi @Mayank Jain, Which @highcharts/dashboards version have you used? Your layouts structure seems to be incompatible with v2.1. Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xn8e17 Also, could you adapt the live example to show the problem?

My dashboard version is 2.1.0 .

As you can see in this live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cdcj2r your structure for gui.layouts is incorrect.
Please check API for Dashboards: https://api.highcharts.com/dashboards/ and compare the structure in my previous example.
